# Pass the Selected Value in DataGridView to ComboBox

Tags: c#, datagridview, combobox

When I clicked on a cell in my DataGridView, the values are passed on my Textboxes, but I have a problem when it comes to my combobox, it just stays null. I've already tried SelectedItem and SelectedIndex but it stays null. I've manage to place the value in my combobox using SelectedText but once I've updated my database, I'm getting a NullReferenceException in my combobox, here's my code:

```
private void dgvStudentRecord_CellContentClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.RowIndex >= 0)
        {
            DataGridViewRow row = this.dgvStudentRecord.Rows[e.RowIndex];
            txtStudNum.Text = row.Cells["studentId"].Value.ToString();
            txtStudName.Text = row.Cells["studentName"].Value.ToString();
            cboSection.SelectedText = row.Cells["section"].Value.ToString();
            numPrelim.Value = Convert.ToDecimal(row.Cells["prelim"].Value);
            numMidterm.Value = Convert.ToDecimal(row.Cells["midterm"].Value);
            numFinals.Value = Convert.ToDecimal(row.Cells["finals"].Value);
        }
    }
```

Comment: when you hover over the `row.Cells["section"].Value.ToString()` in the debugger or QuickWatch, what is the value..?

Comment: what if you change this `cboSection.SelectedText = row.Cells["section"].Value.ToString();` to the following 
`cboSection.SelectedIndex = row.Cells["section"].Value;`

Comment: I get an error cannot implicitly convert string to object.

Comment: What do you want: 1) Add the value as a new Item to the ComboBox.Items or 2) find and select that value in the items collection of the combobox? Use cb.Items.Add for 1) and cb.FindString or cb.FindStringExact for 2). (or write your own find!)

Comment: @TaW 2) find and select that value in the items collection of the combobox

Comment: In that case you should do just that: Note the rules of [FindString](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.combobox.findstring%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) and [FindStringExact](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.combobox.findstringexact%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) - If you want to find inside the items you must write your own method. After you have a (non-negative) index you can set the SelectedIndex, just like in h4xpace's answer..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're going to have some headache doing it the way you are approaching it because the ComboBox does not handle unexpected values well at all, and the SelectText property it not doing what you think its doing (its NOT selecting an item from its internal list when you set that property) (see: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.combobox.selectedtext(v=vs.110).aspx)

You are going to be better of writing something like:

```
int index = cboSection.FindString(row.Cells["section"].Value.ToString());
if(index > -1)
{
   cboSection.SelectedIndex = index;
}
else
{
        object newSection = row.Cells["section"].Value.ToString();
        cboSection.Items.Add(newSection);
        cboSection.SelectedItem = newSection;
}
```

Edited to show conditional select or add.

Final edit... Doh.

Comment: I've tried what you said and get no errors but after i run my program, the combobox is still null after i click an item in datagridview

Comment: So then the item that you are testing for isnt in the list most likely. You should test index to see if its in the list. If its not, add it and select it.

Comment: Ive added items in the combobox using the items(Collection) in the properties. I have a method for adding values to the datagridview, and when i clicked on a cell, it just transfer the values in a textbox and one combobox

Comment: Ok, but the ComboBox still requires you to select one of those items from the list. When you use the FindText method, it does a case insensitive compare over its items collection to see if a match exists. If so, it returns its index. For the sake of example, lets say that when you click on the datagridview, combobox item at index 5 is selected. If you set the SelectedText property of the combobox, then item 5 is still the selected item and its SelectedText is just displayed as whatever you passed in. Make sense?

Comment: Yes sir, i understand. I've tried your edited code above and I'm getting an error in ComboBoxItem. It says could not be found

Comment: Which line? The FindString method or setting the selected item?

Comment: ComboBoxItem newSection = new ComboBoxItem(); the word ComboBoxItem itself

Comment: Sorry about that, I have DevCompenents installed and it tricked me into using their wrapper, change that to just object. See edit: I also forgot to wrap your cell text. Added that too

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/72007/discussion-between-h4xpace-and-aldrin-ramirez).

Answer (score 0):

Try this, `ComboBox.Text` property

```
 combobox1.Text=row.Cells[cellIndex].Value.ToString();
```